# Insert values and default on all others columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, navision

I have a very complexeSQL Server table (over 200 columns) and I want to insert new rows manually. My problem is that i want to manually insert only 3 columns, and the others have to be default. Is there a way to mix

`INSERT INTO [my_table] DEFAULT VALUES` 
and

`INSERT INTO [my_table] ([column_3],[column_5],[column_6]) VALUES ('1','2','3')`

so the added row would be

`DEFAULT | DEFAULT | 1 | DEFAULT | 2 | 3 | DEFAULT | DEFAULT ..and so on..`

Can't find any trick on the net, and I don't want to write 190 "DEFAULT" in a `VALUES` list.

Comment: The actual problem is your table design. 200 columns - something went very wrong there

Comment: Do the columns have default values specified, or does each insert need to have a different "default"?

Comment: No nothing went wrong. I didn't designed this table, it just comes from Microsoft Dynamics NAV, so it's perfectly well to have this number of columns

Comment: If only *some* columns are set at a time, you should use sparse columns. This will save a *lot* of storage. A NAV table probably does that already though.

Comment: @Mureinik they all do have a default value

Comment: @MaximeBTD what is your question? What's wrong with just writing `INSERT ... (col1,col2,col3) VALUES(...)`? The other columns will get their default values or NULL if no defaults are specified

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i dont know, i get the error 'Impossible to insert NULL value in column blabla, insert cancelled'

Comment: @MaximeBTD which means that some non-nullable columns do *NOT* have default values. Or that you actually tried to store a NULL in a non-nullable column. No reason to assume that there is something wrong with INSERT.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok, thank you. I'll try to trick it so. Thanks all for your help

Comment: @MaximeBTD there is nothing to *trick*. Instead of trying to stuff some values somewhere, and probably create a serious business problem, *read* the table's schema and understand what you need to fill. Are there any  default values? Are they *suitable* for what you want to do? Then write a query that fills the required columns with the appropriate values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a column list in an `insert` statement, all the columns **not** specified will get the default value defined for them, or `null` is a value isn't explicitly defined. So, to make a long story short, you should only specify the columns and the values you care about, and let the database handle the other columns itself:

```
INSERT INTO [my_table] 
([column_3], [column_5], [column_6])
VALUES ('1', '2', '3')
```

Comment: Yes that's what i thougt, so if I get an error like 'Impossible to insert NULL value in column_3, column doesn't accept NULL values' that means that no default value is defined ?

Comment: @MaximeBTD was `column_3` specified in the query? If yes, you tried to store a NULL. If no, it means there is no default for this column

Comment: @MaximeBTD yes, assuming it's not specified in the column list. You should alter the table to add a default value to it. E.g.: `ALTER TABLE [my_table] ADD DEFAULT '3' FOR [column_3]`.

Comment: @Mureinik we are talking about ERP tables here. This can be a dangerous advice. The OP should *understand* what's going on first, before ending up with invalid business records. In fact, I suspect that the "defaults" are default ERP entries, *not* database defaults.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you're entirely right. The default values comes from NAV and not the database itself. So yes i'll have to trick it, to get the default values from NAV and then update with my values. This values comes from a PHP app that is supposed to communicate with NAV

Comment: @MaximeBTD I can't repeat strongly enough that there is nothing to trick. The database isn't some Excel file that you can fix later on. In fact, just stop. NAV has an API, use **it** instead of trying to hack its database. *Read* the appropriate values, *construct* the correct objects then *use* the API to send correct commands. It's a REST API, shouldn't be that hard to use

Comment: @MaximeBTD I suggest you post a new question asking about your real problem - how to send specific objects to NAV, not your attempt to bypass the API and hack into the undocumented databases you aren't supposed to modify